# "Where are you going dragon, don't you dare leave your rider behind!" How can a rider keep up with their dragon?

Tags: science-based, dragons, travel

So, let's suppose I finally made it. A creature that's very agile, able to resist most small-arms fire and has a whale-oil breath weapon. Flight is solved with bones, as strong as carbon fiber, (laughs in limpet teeth) and even more muscle on the pecs.

This example dragon's name will be.. Gyvaris.

Now, the dragon also has a rider... which leads to a few problems, namely:

**The dragon simply can't use active flight to gain altitude with that weight on him.**

This isn't a problem if he's to take off from a ledge or any similarly high place, but that's not always possible.

Sometimes they're forced to land in places where dragon and rider can't take off, so usually only the dragon does. Dragons are more vulnerable on the ground, so it's better that way, however, now the rider can't catch up to the dragon. An ODM gear ([if possible](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/162998/what-to-remove-to-make-a-realistic-omni-directional-maneuver-odm-gear)) would still be close to useless in, say, a prairie.

**I've no idea how a dragonrider could catch up to their mount on land, and with lightweight gear, do you have any?**

**FAQ:**

**Why can't a dragon take off with a human?**

[image]

Note the Quetzalcoatlus.

Comment: This feels like you put an artificial constraint on your world for no other reason than to open a thread here. Is this really an issue that you are facing? Why not make the dragon strong enough? If you have a 10 ton dragon, does it really care about a human? This imo isn't good world building. Don't make stuff harder than it needs to be. If this is truly something you need, I'd imagine that you would already have a way in mind. Could you perhaps explain why you need this to be that way so that one can find a suitable answer consistent with your idea?

Comment: If your flight is limited to gliding (probably very poorly, given how much a human weighs) from high places, why bother riding in the first place? Practice falconry with your dragons, that way the big slow human stays behind while the dragon does its thing.

Comment: @Raditz_35 I wish it was artficicial.

Comment: A rope then? Maybe? Please elaborate why this is good world building, I'm curious now

Comment: @Raditz_35 No, I wish the constraints were artificial, like what am I supposed to do when a creature's flapping frequency decreases as their size increases?

Comment: How fast can the dragon fly?

Comment: Dragons should have no problem with the extra weight, any large flying predator, eagle or dragon, still needs the strength to lift any prey it plans on flying back to its nest/infants.              You’ve said nothing of scale, scale would help grant context.                                                       Also I’m imaging a lot of dislocated arms while vainly trying to skyhook a dragon.

Comment: @Raditz_35, "a dragon that can realistically fly and carry a (human) rider" is *not* an artificial constraint. Real world biology and physics have a lot to say about how plausible this is. What would be artificial is to simply pretend the problem doesn't exist. (Granted, that *is* what most stories do, but then most SF has FTL. That's not a reason to discourage people that want to try to be "harder".)

Comment: Maybe the same reason my horse comes back when I fall off?  I like to think it's because he likes me, but realistically I suppose he just knows where the carrots come from.  So carry a supply of dragon treats :-)

Comment: Dunno if this would work but attach a rope to the dragon and use a glider or something to glide behind it? Like they do with speedboats and parachutes and stuff.

Comment: @Matthew I think you are missing my point entirely, this is also not a quote by me or anyone else here. You took your interpretation of the question (which I don't think is actually the question) and put it into quotes (I'm sorry if this is from an older edit) and nobody ever said it. This is not about ignoring real problems. Yes, one could argue that a creature might be to big to fly. Saying this says that all fiction with dragons is bad world building. That's insanity. But that's not even the question. The creature can fly, it just can't take off with a dude for absolutely no reason

Comment: @Raditz_35, yes, that was a summary, not a literal quote, but I think you're missing *my* point. You are ***assuming*** that Mephistopheles just arbitrarily decided "Gyvaris" can't take off with a rider. I am trying to point out that "Gyvaris" has been a work-in-progress for a while (note: there are other questions apparently about the same character), has crunched numbers for lifting capacity, and ran into this issue as a result. (In fairness, mentioning those constraints in the question might help.) Your request for information comes across as... overly hostile.

Comment: @Raditz_35 Both of you, stop fighting now! I DEMAND it!

Answer (score 3):

### In all honesty, he's walking home.

Unless he can steal a horse.

## However

and all of these will require a very well trained dragon.

#### Q airlines

James Bond (I forget the film), releases a balloon on a line that's caught by an aircraft and they fly away. An amusing way to die, certainly not a good way to escape anything but you could play with the idea.

#### Tow launch paraglider

A bit of a technological leap but given enough rope and a paraglider the dragon could potentially tow the rider into the air and then he remounts while airbourne.

#### Hawk pickup

Most dragons are predators, in many cases predatory birds can swoop in and capture prey from the ground/water without losing much speed. The dragon regains height, turns that into airspeed then swoops down to collect the rider while trying not to break his neck on pickup. Maintaining airspeed will allow them to regain enough height to get home.

Comment: Your first idea is basically [Fulton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulton_surface-to-air_recovery_system) for dragons. It might be less lethal than you'd think, as long as you can get a strong enough rope...

Comment: [Relevant xkcd](https://what-if.xkcd.com/149/) (at least, near the end)